# Transitioning through menus in Unity: what is the best option performance-wise?

Tags: unity, performance, menu

I'm making a menu manager and I'm not sure what should I do to make a transition from one menu to the other. What is better to be used performance wise? Here is the step in my mind.

1. Simple enable or disable menu.
2. Change alpha 0 or 1.
3. Move the menu outside of canvas.

So what is better?

Comment: Unity comes with a profiler. Use that, find out.

Comment: I personally store my menu pages as separate scenes.  I would suggest you do the same.  You can always add transition effects to your scene loading/exiting.

Comment: My only thought is that if you change the alpha of the menu the user may still hit those invisible buttons as they are still there. (Not sure if that is the case though)

Comment: Without running the profiler I'd wager that the alpha solution would be the least efficient, as the partial-alpha rendering is going to be "harder" for the GPU than simply moving it off screen (translation is cheap and frustum culling is cheap, alpha blending is hard).

Comment: One question per post please. And I think this question is something you'll have to test on your own. See what works best for you based on your requirements.

Comment: @Almo I agree that this is a try-and-decide-yourself type of question. However, I would be cautious before just recommending people using Unity to use the profiler, since only Unity Pro comes with a profiler. Unity Free doesn't.

Comment: @MAnd incorrect. Unity free profiles now. :) Came with the Version 5 update.

Comment: @Almo Sorry, then! And actually, great to know. Guess I have to go back to it one of theses days to see how it's evolving. Thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: Hey, any time. It's easy to miss that it's now free even if you're using Unity on a regular basis. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you make a menu invisible by making it completely transparent or moving it outside of the view area, any scripts or other components attached to it are still being executed. The best way to show or hide a GUI feature is using `gameObject.SetActive(true)` and `gameObject.SetActive(false)` because this will also prevent the logic behind it from running.